# Compare value with integer sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Here is my database structure: http://prntscr.com/63ftac

I'm trying to make a select query:

```
SELECT * FROM QUESTIONS WHERE TEAM="Albania" UID!='2'  LIMIT 1
```

But I get a syntax error:

```
 near "UID": syntax error
 ﹕ android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException:
near "UID": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM QUESTIONS 
WHERE TEAM="Albania" UID!='2'  LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `AND`:

```
SELECT * FROM QUESTIONS WHERE TEAM="Albania" AND UID!="2" LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Becuase you missed `AND` between conditions,So rewrite as

```
SELECT * FROM QUESTIONS WHERE TEAM="Albania" AND UID!='2'  LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax seems to be incorrect. When you want to include more than one condition in `WHERE` clause, use `AND` keyword like here:

```
SELECT * FROM QUESTIONS WHERE TEAM="Albania" AND UID!='2'  LIMIT 1
```